# Inequality.$\frac{ab}{\sqrt{ab+2c^2}}+\frac{bc}{\sqrt{bc+2a^2}}+\frac{ca}{\sqrt{ca+2b^2}} \geq \sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c > 0$. Prove that **(using Hölder's inequality):**

$$\frac{ab}{\sqrt{ab+2c^2}}+\frac{bc}{\sqrt{bc+2a^2}}+\frac{ca}{\sqrt{ca+2b^2}} \geq \sqrt{ab+bc+ca}.$$

Thanks :)

I tried to apply Hölder's inequality how I apply in this [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193751/inequality-fracx319y2xz-fracy319z2yx-fracz319x2yz-geq) but I didn't obtained anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Hölder's inequality, we get
$$
\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac {ab}{\sqrt{ab + 2c^2}}\right) \left(\sum_{cyc} \frac {ab}{\sqrt{ab + 2c^2}}\right) \left(\sum_{cyc} ab (ab + 2c^2)\right) \geq (ab + bc + ca)^3
$$
The above inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac {ab}{\sqrt{ab + 2c^2}}\right)^2 (ab + bc +ca)^2 \geq (ab + bc + ca)^3
$$
And so
$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac {ab}{\sqrt{ab + 2c^2}} \geq \sqrt{ab + bc + ca}
$$